# Unset same variable from different array

Tags: php, variables, global-variables

I need to unset a variable from `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST`.

As if now I do it simply by calling unset three time.

```
unset( $_GET['add-to-cart'] );
unset( $_POST['add-to-cart'] );
unset( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] );
```

Is there any simple code for doing this ?

Right now creating a custom function only seem to be the alternative to me, Is there any single line code for this ?

Thank You

Comment: Why not just use `$_REQUEST` consistently, and only unset it from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put it in one line:

```
unset($_GET['add-to-cart'], $_POST['add-to-cart'], $_REQUEST['add-to-cart']);
```